# Error with ProGuard while obfuscating Maven testing framework

Tags: java, maven, automation, frameworks, proguard-maven-plugin

I'm encountering the above error when attempting to run mvn clean package. I have a Maven test framework with one test class containing a method, and a main class that creates an object of the test class and calls the method. I haven't specified anything in proguard.cfg.

I'm encountering the above error when attempting to run mvn clean package.

```
[INFO] execute ProGuard [-injars, 'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\Desktop\ProguardValidation\target\ProguardValidation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'(!META-INF/maven/**) ...'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\Desktop\ProguardValidation\target\ProguardValidation-1.0-SNAPSHOT-small.jar', -include, 'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRa
jak\Desktop\ProguardValidation\src\main\resources\proguard.cfg', -libraryjars, 'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\Desktop\ProguardValidation\target\tempLibrary
jars\0', -printmapping, 'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\Desktop\ProguardValidation\target\proguard_map.txt', -printseeds, 'C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\Deskto
p\ProguardValidation\target\proguard_seed.txt']
[INFO] proguard jar: [C:\Users\DheerajKumarRajak\.m2\repository\com\guardsquare\proguard-base\7.2.2\proguard-base-7.2.2.jar]
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 7.2.2Warning: org.example.Main: can't find superclass or interface java.lang.ObjectWarning: org.example.test: can't find s
uperclass or interface java.lang.ObjectWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced class java.lang.ObjectWarning: org.example.Main: can't find refe
renced class java.lang.ObjectWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced clas
s java.lang.ClassWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced class java.lang.
StringWarning: org.example.Main: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.ObjectWarn
ing: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.ObjectWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: org.ex
ample.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.SystemWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.SystemWarning: org.example.test
: can't find referenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringWarning: org.example.test: can't fin
d referenced class java.io.PrintStreamWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.io.PrintStreamWarning: org.example.test: can't find re
ferenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: org.example.test: can't find referenced class java.lang.ClassWarning: there were 20 unresolved references to clas
ses or interfaces.         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.         If your code works fine without the missing classe
s, you can suppress         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.         (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass)
Unexpected error java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
 [proguard]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:544) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
 [proguard]     at proguard.pass.PassRunner.run(PassRunner.java:24) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
 [proguard]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:328) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
 [proguard]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:130) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
 [proguard]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:623) [proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.531 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-12T11:11:45+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.wvengen:proguard-maven-plugin:2.6.0:proguard (default) on project Proguard Validation: Obfuscation failed

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProguardValidation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <putLibraryJarsInTempDir>true</putLibraryJarsInTempDir>
                    <proguardVersion>7.2.2</proguardVersion>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                    <injar>ProguardValidation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</injar>
                    <outjar>ProguardValidation-1.0-SNAPSHOT-small.jar</outjar>
                    <proguardInclude>src/main/resources/proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please format the error log correctly. It looks like a multiline stacktrace in a single line. That makes it very hard to read. Also provide the pom configuration and what do you mean by your "Maven test framework". What are you using proguard for exactly?

Comment: I have shared pom.xml and error. The reason for using proguard is we provide frameworks to external companies for use in their projects. One of our key concerns is safeguarding. By hiding the implementation details, we aim to ensure that the core logic behind the framework remain proprietary and inaccessible to others. Maven test framework which we have created for testing.